# Is it possible to use a Network Loadbalancer to a ECS serbvice that is using UDP protocol?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to set up an Elasticsearch container in AWS ECS while also listening to UDP.

Basically I want to route UDP traffic to a ECS through the Network Loadbalancer.

Is this possible with ECS?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the Network Load Balancers in EC2 support UDP, TCP and TLS, where as the Application Load balancers are for HTTP and HTTPS.

If you want both HTTP and UDP to be routed to the same instance I think you could setup two load balancers (one Application and one Network), or since HTTP uses TCP, you could probably just use the Network Load balancer and route both TCP and UDP traffic to that instance.